# I am looking for assistance with achieving remote management bypass on a MacBook Pro 2020 13 inch intel

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, usb, startup, ssd

I have referred to many threads on the internet. Essentially it comes down to this. I have purchased a MacBook Pro through Offer up. I went to activate it and it has a remote management lock on it. I have done research and this means it is not officially stolen, which is some what a relief. However, essentially the Mac book is useless until I can remove this remote management feature. Keep in mind I know zero coding logic but I can type out code in terminal that is given to me.

**TIME LINE**

- I want to install Catalina via an external USB drive. So I can create an admin account.
- Complete creating a USB boot drive. However, When I attempt to select boot drive, the Mac doesn't allow boot up from an external drive. The USB will not even appear.
- Go into recovery mode to enable Mac to boot from external drive, via security settings. However when I go to do this, it states there is no admin in existence.
- I do some more research, essentially I'm supposed to go into single user mode and type some code to enable myself to create an admin account. Then I can change the security settings. ok cool no biggie...
- The Mac will not let me go into single user mode. It will show the white text and black background but no terminal after all of that. Seems like it is nearly impossible to enable single user mode terminal.
- I decide to erase all SSD via disk utility, However there is a partition called Base system that I cannot erase. I restart, and reset my NVRAM first thing.
- I turn on again, press option to load boot disks. Only internet recovery mode pops up. I do not want to connect to Wi-Fi as it will register the remote management lock after reseting everything. I am certain in this state the remote lock has not been recognized by the computer.
- I don't understand why it won't accept my USB boot drive after clearing disks, and then reseting NVRAM.

There has to be some way to crack this Rosetta Stone. I am open to all ideas.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to find a way to access system preferences via remote log in screen, but I do not have the admin privileges. I was actually able to open my Catalina install..but I needed the admin password to follow through with it. I know I can download applications onto a usb and open them now. Also I have access to terminal. Essentially I can open anything that's in the finder. I will attach pictures.

https://prnt.sc/1lwb07m (finder)

https://prnt.sc/1lwbdo8 (terminal)

https://prnt.sc/1lwbx2s (applications)

https://prnt.sc/1lvqu8s (system preferences)

https://prnt.sc/1lvptb7 (admin log in request)

Now that you know what im working with. Is there anything I can do that would give me admin controls?
Thanks,
Ben

P.S I will delete this thread if it works. I understand this is some very valuable information if it becomes bypassed.

Comment: Remote management is **DESIGNED** to make it impossible for you to do anything with the computer like what you want to do. Until you get the previous owner to unlock the system and remove it from their MDM the likelihood of you doing anything beyond using it *as is* is pretty small.

Comment: Basically all you can do is ask for your money back.

Comment: You have a perfectly functioning door stop, until you get the remote management properly unlocked.

Comment: Also… T2 security will prevent you from booting off anything other than the internal drive or Internet Recovery. Single user cannot be used any more as a 'cheat'. That was shut out a few years ago. You're left with contacting the registered owner & asking them to release it (It's not unknown for it to have been forgotten), or demanding your money back from the seller. Modern Macs are a brick if they're locked. An Apple Store will release it with proof of ownership… but as you can't actually provide that, only proof of purchase, which is not the same thing.

Comment: …and you cannot replace the SSD on a 2020 MBP, it's soldered to the logic board

Comment: @Tetsujin jeeeeeez what a headache. Would replacing the logic board would do anything

Comment: @SteveChambers I can tell

Comment: @SolarMike no s777 mike. im trying to get it properly unlocked

Comment: You'd have to unlock it before Apple would accept it for a logic board replacement… I'm not sure anyone else can do full board replacements on newer Macs, it's pretty much the whole computer